# Invalid use of template-name ‘Matrix’ without an argument list

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

Here is my Matrix.cpp file. (there's a separate Matrix.h file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix<T>(int r, int c, T fill = 1)
{
  if (r > maxLength || c > maxLength) {
    cerr << "Number of rows and columns should not exceed " << maxLen << endl;
    throw 1;
  }

  if (r < 0 || c < 0) {
    cerr << "The values for the number of rows and columns should be positive" << endl;
    throw 2;
  }

  rows = r;
  cols = c;

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
      mat[i][j] = fill;

}
```

This gives the following

> error: invalid use of template-name ‘Matrix’ without an argument list

What's the problem in my code?

EDIT: The class Matrix is defined with a `template<class T>`

EDIT:
Here's my Matrix.h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#define maxLength 10;

using namespace std;

template <class T>

class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(int r, int c, T fill = 1);

private:
    int rows, cols;
        T mat[10][10];
};
```

And here's the Matrix.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int r, int c, T fill = 1)
{
}
```

This gives the following error:

> Matrix.cpp:12:43: error: default argument given for parameter 3 of
>   ‘Matrix::Matrix(int, int, T)’ Matrix.h:16:3: error: after previous
>   specification in ‘Matrix::Matrix(int, int, T)’

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: So why exactly don't you tell us in which line that error is?

Comment: Error is in the line `Matrix::Matrix<T>(int r, int c, T fill = 1)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your class is template then correct definition should be,

```
template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int r, int c, T fill)  // don't give default argument
...
```

Also, don't forget to include this Cpp file where you use this class. Because in the case of templates, full body should be visible to all translation units.

**Edit**: After your edited question, I noticed that the error says it all.

You are not suppose to give the default argument inside the definition of the method. It's adequate to give in the declaration(which you already gave). Make your `template` definition as shown above and the error shall disappear.

Comment: Where should the above code be? I changed like that in Matrix.cpp above and it still gives the error. :S

Comment: @thameera, what error it is giving. Have you `#include` `Matrix.cpp` file as I suggested in my answer ? For `template`s you have to show al declaration and definition to the code which is using it. That's why people try to make `template` definition within the `class` body.

Comment: I've edited the question with Matrix.h, Matrix.cpp and the errors. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @thameera, see the edited answer. The problem seems to be with default argument.

Answer (score 3):

You should write as:

```
template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int r, int c, T fill = 1)
{
  ..
}
```

Yes, it's tedious. And it might not be a good idea to put
the template definitions in the source file, refer to
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12

So the easiest way is to put the definitions of the template members
inside the class template definition in header file.

Comment: Can you give us the definition of Matrix, i.e., "Matrix.h" so that we can take a look?

Comment: I've edited the question with Matrix.h, Matrix.cpp and the errors. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @thameera: What is wrong is a default argument in definition - it can go only with declarations.